# 2nd node child process fails to run on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

So I needed a way to restart my bot within itself and came up with this eventually, however when testing on a Raspberry Pi using ssh it exits after the first child process ends, whereas on Windows it continuously repeats this cycle

Run using node run.js

run.js

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

var bot;

function startBot() {
  bot = spawn('node', ["bot.js"]);

  bot.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
  bot.stderr.on('data', data => console.error(data.toString()));

  bot.on('close', code => {
    if (code === 1234) startBot();
  });
}

startBot();
```

bot.js

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("child process exiting...");
  process.exit(1234);
}, 5000)
```

Output on Windows:

```
PS C:\Users\[removed]\Desktop\despacito\despacito-spider\test> node run.js
child process exiting...


child process exiting...

child process exiting...

child process exiting...

child process exiting...
```

Output on the Raspi

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/despacito-spider/test $ node run.js
child process exiting...

pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/despacito-spider/test $
```

Comment: Have you tried to log in bot.on('closes')? Or even the pid of each process? It's a strange behavior, but those are the first check that I would do.

Comment: `bot.on('closes')` does not work.
Pids are different. It appears the .on is called, however the exit code is always 210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is very rare for programs to exit with status codes greater than 128, in part because programmers avoid it due to the $? ambiguity.

From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99143) answer

Changing the exit code to 2 made it work